# Plot in R won't change color

Tags: r, colors, plot

This is probably going to sound like a really stupid question but my plot in R will not change color!

this is my line in R

```
plot(MasterModCfs$V3,MasterModCfs$V5,col="blue")
```

I have tried it with spaces and without, with different colors, reloading, everything I could think of. If it's important, MasterModCfs contains literally thousands of data values.

I did one of the examples just to check

```
cars <- c(1, 3, 6, 4, 9)
plot(cars)
plot(cars, col="blue")
```

and it's blue. So that works.

Why won't my plot change colors?

Comment: Is your first plot otherwise ok, just in black instead of blue?

Comment: What is `class(MasterModCfs$V3)`? Are you only drawing to screen? Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Does this work:  `par(col="blue"); plot(MasterModCfs$V3,MasterModCfs$V5); box(col="black")`?

Comment: @RStudent yes, it works fine otherwise

Comment: @user3736201 Maybe you do what MrFlick suggested and tell us what `class(MasterModCfs$V3)` returns?

Answer (score 2):

Googling the same problem, I came across this present page - but subsequently found the source of my own issue through trial and error so posting here in case it helps. My x axis values were set up as factors - when I re-converted them to a normal string using as.character(), I was able to re-apply my own colours finally.

Comment: Mine was in POSIXct format and didn't work. Change it to as.Date and it worked. Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your par() settings are and what the classes of your columns, it's impossible to say.

You might try adding 'pch=21, bg="red"' to your plot command and see if that changes anything. It might give you a hint.

Comment: this seems more like a comment than an answer (perhaps you don't have enough reputation to comment?)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the `aes` command in `ggplot2`. You can try

```
ggplot(data = MasterModCfs) + geom_point (mapping =aes (x=V3, y=V5), color="blue")
```

That should work!

Using plot directly I am not sure how to do it. I try your simple example (with cars) but it also fails if you add another vector for the "y" axis (as you wish to do in the end). To be honest, I have no idea why it works using only "cars" and the color.